# SharePoint 2010 itemadded event receiver - how to check logs?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, event-receiver

I have created a custom SharePoint 2010 Item added event receiver on a document library. I also log all exception which might be fired during this event receiver. 
This event receiver fires perfectly fine almost all of the times. There are, however, only a few cases during which the event receiver does not fire. and since the event receiver does not fire I don't see any exception log. These types of events are scattered and not concentrated on a particular timespan of the day.

My question is whether there is some log that I can check on a SharePoint server that will tell me why the event receiver did not fire or probably what went wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, event receivers **will just stop** when an uncatched exception occurs.  So they will not log exceptions themselves.

What you should do is make your event logic exception-proof, so catch everything you can and log it yourself to the ULS.

Comment: All my event logic is inside a parent try/catch block and exceptions are logged in uls only. If that is what you mean.